# CartoCSS different background colors of Map element

Tags: tilemill, cartocss

I tried to change the background color of a map in zoomlevels greater than 11, but

```
Map{ 
  background-color:@water;
  [zoom>11]{background-color:@water*1.05;}
}
```

had no effect.
Is there an other way in CartoCSS to change the background-color for different zoom levels?

Comment: Think you can only control different colours if it is a layer (point,line,polygon) not the static background.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a workaround: I created a polygon covers the whole world in GeoJSON and added it as layer #backgound.

```
{
    "type": "Polygon",
    "coordinates": [
        [
            [-180, 89.9],
            [180, 89.9],
            [180, -89.9],
            [-180,-89.9],
            [-180,89.9]
        ]
    ]
}
```

now i can use this polygon as background

```
#background {
  polygon-fill:@water;
  [zoom>11]{polygon-fill:@water*1.05;}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same issue and found another solution: [global-pattern](https://www.mapbox.com/tilemill/docs/guides/styling-polygons/#global-patterns).

Comment: Welcome to GIS@SE .. It would help if you described your solution for future readers .. Best Regards